# for what use dot after comand "ls" in linux? ~ ls

Tags: python, linux

using the command ~ls allows you to list files, which is difference if I add dot ~ls . ?

sorry for my english, I am practicing

Comment: single (dot) `.` represents current working directory.

Comment: For general computer questions, please post on [su]. Stack Overflow is only for _programming_ questions.

Answer (score 1):

dot shows the folder you are in. If u re in downloads. **ls .** shows downloads. In your situation, ls (without a directory argument) is going to list directories and files under the current directory(pwd).